# Include conditional checking in query with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Suggestion either in C# or VB.NET are welcome.

Table relationship:

- Student 1:N TimeSheet (FK StudentId)
- TimeSheet 1:N TimeRecord (FK TimeSheetId)

  ```
  Dim query = From s In db.Students _
              Let pair = (From ts In db.TimeSheets _
              Join tr In db.TimeRecords On tr.TimeSheetId Equals ts.TimeSheetId _
              Where ts.IsArchive = False And ts.IsCompleted = False _
              Group By key = New With {ts.TimeSheetId, ts.StudentId} Into TotalHour = Sum(tr.BonusHour)) _
              From part In pair _
              Where part.key.StudentId = s.StudentId _
              Select New With {.StudentId = s.StudentId, .AssignedId = s.AssignedId,.TotalTime = part.TotalHour}
  ```

Here's the result of the query:

- 734 -- 159 : 9 hrs 35 mm 28 sec
- 2655 -- 160 : 93 hrs 33 mm 50 sec
- 1566 -- 161 : 37 hrs 23 mm 53 sec
- 3114 -- 162 : 25 hrs 0 mm 21 sec

Wanted result of query:

- **733 -- 158 : 0 hr 0mm 0 sec**
- 734 -- 159 : 9 hrs 35 mm 28 sec
- **736 -- 169 : 0 hrs 0mm 0sec**
- 2655 -- 160 : 93 hrs 33 mm 50 sec
- 1566 -- 161 : 37 hrs 23 mm 53 sec
- 3114 -- 162 : 25 hrs 0 mm 21 sec
- **2165 -- 189 : 0 hr 0 mm 21 sec**

There are some TimeSheet that have no TimeRecord, which I need to select as well. How can I select all of them to make selection like above wanted result? I'm thinking of how I can include some condtion
checking in the query to see if this TimeSheet has no TimeRecord then no need to Sum(tr.BonusHour) just assign TotalHour to zero. I don't know it's right way to go.

Any sugestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this with the `Sum` (C#):

```
Sum(tr.BonusHour ?? 0)
```

which would be the same as

```
Sum(tr.BonusHour != null ? tr.BonusHour : 0)
```

I am not sure what type your `BonusHour` has, so you would use zero-correspondent object of this type instead of the `0` in the sample.